# MySQL MAX in Join Query

Tags: mysql, join, max

I would like to join two tables on a MAX value.

The max(lg) are correct but the 'event' column wont load correctly.

Below are my example tables and desired output...

Im using...

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.name
     , b_lg
     , b_event
  FROM TABLE_A a
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MAX(lg) as b_lg
            , event as b_event
            , enrolid as b_enrolid 
         FROM TABLE_B 
        GROUP 
           BY lg) b
    ON a.id = b_enrolid
 GROUP BY a.id
```

####### TABLEA ########

```
  id |    name        |
   1 |     John       |
   2 |     Mike       |
   3 |     Dave       |
   4 |     Sarah      |
```

################# TABLEB ###############

```
  id |  enrolid |    lg     |  event   |
   1 |  1       |    10     |    A     |
   2 |  2       |    20     |    B     |
   3 |  1       |    30     |    C     |
   4 |  2       |    60     |    D     |
   5 |  2       |    50     |    E     |
   6 |  3       |    60     |    F     |
   7 |  1       |    70     |    G     |
   8 |  3       |    20     |    H     |
```

###### DESIRED OUTPUT #####

```
  id |  name       |   lg   |   event   |
   1 |  John       |   70   |     G     |
   2 |  Mike       |   60   |     D     |
   3 |  Dave       |   60   |     F     |
   4 |  Sara       |  NULL  |   NULL    |
```

Comment: Sound like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Before trying to fix this join, what is your actual goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It figures out the `MAX` value of `lg` for each `enrolid` and then uses those values to `LEFT JOIN` to `Table_A` to get the `name` and `Table_B` to get the `event`:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.lg, B.event
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT enrolid, MAX(lg) AS max_lg
           FROM Table_B
           GROUP BY enrolid) M ON M.enrolid = A.id
LEFT JOIN Table_B B ON B.enrolid = M.enrolid AND B.lg = M.max_lg
ORDER BY A.id
```

Output:

```
id  name    lg      event
1   John    70      G
2   Mike    60      D
3   Dave    60      F
4   Sarah   null    null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fvn5iwoPhcJxUSmRXzKaQP/0)

Comment: Thank you Nick! That works as it supposed to and I was actually thinking about a double join I just could not believe that such a simple query (from the results perspective of view) could be so overcomplicated. Logically if the MAX is already selected from a row I'd expect the other column to be fetched from the same row aswell but hey-ho... the computer sez no :D I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1680430 yeah - life would be *much* simpler if that was the case. Unfortunately none of the SQL engines work that way, they all give you an indeterminate result.